# Help check solution to likelihood test ratio

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hypothesis-testing

This is the question I am attempting:

[image]

This is the provided solution:

[image]

I am not able to arrive at the final solution.

---

**Question 1**

The part where my solution differs is at (I). I have:
$$ \frac{2n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i -\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i } = \frac{2n}{n\bar{x}-n\bar{x}} = \frac{2n}{n(\bar{x}-\bar{y})}=\frac{2}{\bar{x}-\bar{y}}$$

How do I get the $+$ in the denominator?

---

**Question 2**

Furthermore, assuming that (I) is correct I am not able to get the last equality in (II). I got $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}\frac{(\bar{x}+\bar{y})^{2n}}{(\bar{x}\bar{y})^n}$$. What rules can I use to further simplify this expression?

---

**Question 3**

Lastly, if I assume (II) is true, I am still not able to get (III). The furthest I got is: $$ -4n\log(2) + 2\log(\bar{x}+\bar{y}) - \log(\bar{x}) + \log(\bar{y})$$. I have to idea how to combine the last 3 terms into  a single expression like to the solution did. Please help.

Comment: Seems like there's a typo in the book's calculation already $2$ equations prior to your (I) where the $-$ should be a +.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure the reason behind the $\pm$ issue in your first request, I think this is a typo. For your second I wonder if it has (for reasons beyond me) been re-written as
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}\frac{(\bar{x}+\bar{y})^{2n}}{(\bar{x}\bar{y})^n} &=&  \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}\frac{(\bar{x}+\bar{y})^{2n}}{(\sqrt{\bar{x}\bar{y}})^{2n}} \\
    &=& 
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}\left(\frac{\bar{x}+\bar{y}}{\sqrt{\bar{x}\bar{y}}}\right)^{2n}          
\end{eqnarray}
As you can see I can't describe why the final answer in the printed answer is not of a power of $2n$. I think this is in error in your book/article. However, following the calculation through, we find;
\begin{eqnarray}
\log r( x,y) &=& -2n \log 2 + 2n log \left(\frac{\bar{x}+\bar{y}}{\sqrt{\bar{x}\bar{y}}}\right) \\
             &=& -2n \log 2 + 2n log \left( \frac{\sqrt{\bar{x}}}{\sqrt{\bar{y}}} + \frac{\sqrt{\bar{y}}}{\sqrt{\bar{x}}}
 \right) \\
             &=& -2n \log 2 + 2n log \left( \sqrt{\frac{\bar{x}}{\bar{y}}}
 + \sqrt{\frac{\bar{y}}{\bar{x}}}
 \right)
\end{eqnarray}
The above result is now found by multiplying it by 2. The penultimate line in the above formulation was obtained by making use of the identity
\begin{equation}
\frac{a}{\sqrt{a}} = \sqrt{a}
\end{equation}
For $a \neq 0$.

Any other issues, please let me know,
Best,
A.

Comment: Why is there a downvote?

Comment: @mauna Not sure-thought it was a reasonable approach to your question. Hey ho, life goes on. Hope it makes sense to you.